# Выдает ошибку 3221225477

Tags: c++, devc++

Я не так давно в C++, нужна помощь. В главном файле создаю объект `Task`, вызываю функцию `createTask()`. Компилится без предупреждений и ошибок. Запускаю, ввожу `title`(первый `cin`) и **выдает ошибку: 3221225477**.
Версия *Dev-Cpp 5.11*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned int ID = 0;
char nowTitle[150] = "0";
char nowBody[3000] = "0";

class Task
{
    private:
        char* title;
        char* body;
        int iden;
        bool isDone;
    
    public:
        Task(): isDone(false) 
            { iden = ++ID; };
        void createTask();
        void dispTask();
        void dispTaskName();        //for TaskList
        void recordTask();          //record task in file
        void loadTask();            //load of file in class (int)
        void taskIsDone();
        
};


//-----------------------___Task___-----------------------

void Task::createTask()
{
    cout << "Add task header: "; 
    cin.get(nowTitle, 150, '.');                                    //the maximum size of the title - 150
    cout << "Add task description:\n"
         << "(For end input description, press equal)\n"; 
    cin.get(nowBody, 3000, '=');                                    // the maximum size of the body - 3000
    
    title = &nowTitle;
    body = &nowBody;
                                                                    //----------------------------- << add void recordTask >> 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вот это

```
title = &nowTitle;
body = &nowBody;
```

у вас вообще компилироваться не должно. Если написать

```
title = nowTitle;
body = nowBody;
```

то скомпилируется, но так писать тоже не надо!! Смотрите - `nowTitle` и `nowBody` у вас - глобальные массивы. Так что после `title = nowTitle;` ваш экземпляр `Task` будет считать, что его заголовок лежит в глобальной переменной (кстати, если вы потом напишете в деструкторе `delete[]title`, то получите новых неприятностей - удаляя глобальный объект...). Потом создается второй `Task` и переписывает этот массив. Voila - у обоих Task'ов одинаковый заголовок.

Старайтесь вообще избегать глобальных переменных - как только можете. Это уже ultima ratio, если иначе совсем никак...

Выделяйте память для `title` и `body` прямо в классе - хоть статически, если еще не в курсе про динамическое выделение. Они же для каждого экземпляра - свои. Так будет правильнее :)